# Custom Event Handler - How to define WithEvents?

Tags: excel, vba, events, event-handling, eventhandler

I'm trying to create a very simple custom event handler

```
Public Event wshActivate(ID As Long, ByRef cancel As Boolean)

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim numba As Long: numba = 10
    Dim cancel As Boolean: cancel = False

    RaiseEvent wshActivate(numba, cancel)

End Sub
```

What I don't get is how I'm supposed to define the `WithEvents` listener? How do I know this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your intentions, but I have created something what works, based on your sample. First you need to have a Class module named `Class1`.

[image]

In ThisWorkbook module I have this code:

```
Private WithEvents cls As Class1

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set cls = New Class1
    cls.ImportantFunctionFromClass
End Sub

Private Sub cls_wshActivate(ID As Long, cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "this is a msg from an event inide the ImportantFunction"
End Sub
```

Class1:

```
Public Event wshActivate(ID As Long, ByRef cancel As Boolean)

Sub ImportantFunctionFromClass()
    Dim numba As Long: numba = 10
    Dim cancel As Boolean: cancel = False

    '...some relevant code...

    RaiseEvent wshActivate(numba, cancel)

    '...some relevant code...

End Sub
```

You can see I have put `WithEvents` in ThisWorkbook module.